# Trying to make an approval system and cant get the bot to recognise when I react with the selected emojies

Tags: discord.js

I am attempting to create a request system with an approval system and am trying to get the basic reaction system to work (eventually it hopefully should react to a embed it creates not the command), anyway it reacts to the command however when you react it doesnt recognise it and after the set time it just sends the timeout message

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.user.id;
};

message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] } ) 
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            message.channel.send('you reacted with a thumbs up.');
        }
        else {
            message.reply('you reacted with a thumbs down.');
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        console.log(`After a minute, only ${collected.size} out of 4 reacted.`);
     message.reply('you didn\'t react with neither a thumbs up, nor a thumbs down.');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a slight error in your `filter`, with the part that checks the `user`'s ID. [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) does not have a `user` property. Instead, you should use [`author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author), which returns a `User`.

This means that you have to use

```js
user.id === message.author.id
```

instead of

```js
user.id === message.user.id
```

---

Here's the [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) that you can use for reference.